# typed vs untyped vs expr vs stmt in templates and macros

Tags: templates, macros, nim-lang

I've been lately using templates and macros, but i have to say i have barely found information about these important types. This is my superficial understanding:

- typed/expr is something that must exists previously, but you can use .immediate. to overcome them.
- untyped/stmt is something that doesn't to be defined previously/one or more statements.

This is a very vague notion of the types. I'd like to have a better explanation of them, including which types should be used as return.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The goal of these different parameter types is to give you several increasing levels of precision in specifying what the compiler should accept as a parameter to the macro.

Let's imagine a hypothetical macro that can solve mathematical equations. It will be used like this:

```
solve(x + 10 = 25) # figures out that the correct value for x is 15
```

Here, the macro just cares about the structure of the supplied AST tree. It doesn't require that the same tree is a valid expression in the current scope (i.e. that `x` is defined and so on). The macro just takes advantage of the Nim parser that already can decode most of the mathematical equations to turn them into easier to handle AST trees. That's what `untyped` parameters are for. They don't get semantically checked and you get the raw AST.

On the next step in the precision ladder are the `typed` parameters. They allow us to write a generic kind of macro that will accept any expression, as long as it has a proper meaning in the current scope (i.e. its type can be determined). Besides catching errors earlier, this also has the advantage that we can now work with the type of the expression within the macro body (using the `macros.getType` proc).

We can get even more precise by requiring an expression of a specific type (either a concrete type or a type class/concept). The macro will now be able to participate in overload resolution like a regular proc. It's important to understand that the macro will still receive an AST tree, as it will accept both expressions that can be evaluated at compile-time and expressions that can only be evaluated at run-time.

Finally, we can require that the macro receives a value of specific type that is supplied at compile-time. The macro can work with this value to parametrise the code generation. This is realm of the [static parameters](http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#special-types-static-t). Within the body of the macro, they are no longer AST trees, but rather ordinary well typed values.

So far, we've only talked about expressions, but Nim's macros also accept and produce blocks and this is the second axis, which we can control. `expr` generally means a single expression, while `stmt` denotes a list of expressions (historically, its name comes from StatementList, which existed as a separate concept before expressions and statements were unified in Nim).

The distinction is most easily illustrated with the return types of templates. Consider the `newException` template from the system module:

```
template newException*(exceptn: typedesc, message: string): expr =
  ## creates an exception object of type ``exceptn`` and sets its ``msg`` field
  ## to `message`. Returns the new exception object.
  var
    e: ref exceptn
  new(e)
  e.msg = message
  e
```

Even thought it takes several steps to construct an exception, by specifying `expr` as the return type of the template, we tell the compiler that only that last expression will be considered as the return value of the template. The rest of the statements will be inlined, but cleverly hidden from the calling code.

As another example, let's define a special assignment operator that can emulate the semantics of C/C++, allowing assignments within if statements:

```
template `:=` (a: untyped, b: typed): bool =
  var a = b
  a != nil

if f := open("foo"):
  ...
```

Specifying a concrete type has the same semantics as using `expr`. If we had used the default `stmt` return type instead, the compiler wouldn't have allowed us to pass a "list of expressions", because the if statement obviously expects a single expression.

`.immediate.` is a legacy from a long-gone past, when templates and macros didn't participate in overload resolution. When we first made them aware of the type system, plenty of code needed the current `untyped` parameters, but it was too hard to refactor the compiler to introduce them from the start and instead we added the `.immediate.` pragma as a way to force the backward-compatible behaviour for the whole macro/template.

With `typed/untyped`, you have a more granular control over the individual parameters of the macro and the `.immediate.` pragma will be gradually phased out and deprecated.