# How to get string representation of an expr in Nim template

Tags: generic-programming, nim-lang

Is there a possibility to get string representation of an expression (or an identifier) inside a `template`? For example, having the next code:

```
template `*`*(name: expr) {.immediate.} =
  var `name`* {.inject.}: string = ""
  # Want to print 'name' here, not its value like with backticks
```

Is it possible to get the string representation of the `name` expression inside a template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `astToStr` magic from the system module to do this:

```
template foo*(name: untyped) =
  var `name`* {.inject.}: string = ""
  # Want to print 'name' here, not its value like with backticks
  echo "the variable name is ", name.astToStr

foo test
```

The output will be:

```
the variable name is test
```

The use of the `immediate` pragma is discouraged with the latest version of the compiler. See the following answer for more details:
[typed vs untyped vs expr vs stmt in templates and macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367313/typed-vs-untyped-vs-expr-vs-stmt-in-templates-and-macros/31372326#31372326)