# expression 'T' is of type 'type int' and has to be discarded

Tags: templates, nim-lang

Say I just want a template to "generate" a type, from a generic argument, and use the template's invocation in places where a type is expected:

```
template p[T] = T
var a: p[int]()
```

> (3, 14) Error: expression 'T' is of type 'type int' and has to be
>   discarded

lol, really ?
I hope I'm just being a newbie and there is indeed a way (hopefully uncontrived) to do that.

Note that it's the same output, with a non generic attempt:

```
template p(t: typedesc) = t
var a: p(int)
```

EDIT: reading [this insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31372326/893406), I realized the system might feel more patted on the back if we specified the templates's return type; adding `: untyped` before `= t` got the previous snippets to build. any explanation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template p[T] = T
var a: p[int]()
```

This is the same as:

```
template p[T]: void = T
var a: p[int]()
```

You're telling the compiler that your template returns nothing, this is why it complains.

So you need to specify the return type...

```
template p[T]: typedesc = T
var a: p[int]()
```

Then it works fine. This behaviour extends to procedures and methods in Nim, not specifying a return type means that there is no return value.

Answer (score 2):

Compile-time functions mapping from types to types in Nim are usually implemented with [`typedesc` parameters](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#special-types-typedesc). Compared to generic params, this has the additional benefit of allowing to provide multiple overloads handling different types in different ways:

```
type
  Foo = object

# handler all integer types:
template myTypeMapping(T: typedesc[SomeInteger]): typedesc = string 

# specific handling of the Foo type:
template myTypeMapping(T: typedesc[Foo]): typedesc = seq[string]

# all sequence types are not re-mapped:
template myTypeMapping(T: typedesc[seq]): typedesc = T
```

Please note that you always need to specify that your template has a `typedesc` return type.

Comment: generic parameters have the convenience of being deduced. we lose this with typedesc parameters ?

Comment: well, they can be deduced only when the template has other params. When the type itself is a required param, then my suggestion is to always use `typedesc`.